# Can Agora be used to implement video chat functionality with .NET 7?

Tags: c#, .net, angular, agora.io

Currently my project uses .NET 7 and Angular 16. Can I do video chat functionality with .NET integrating Agora API?

Looking at the documentation, it seems that Agora does not support .NET.
Can anyone give me an example of .NET with Agora.